# Web UI to visualise a timeline of events?

Tags: javascript, visualization

I'm looking at storing and presenting event data in a web-based UI.

There are a few complications, however:

- There is a very high density of events - hundreds of them every second.
- Events are spaced at very small time intervals - e.g. every few microseconds.
- There's a need to be able to zoom out to see the macro picture - e.g. over the day, or, over a few minutes, as well as the micro picture - i.e. down to individual events.

I was thinking of doing some kind of timeline, that you could scroll in sync with a list of events, however, I'm not sure of the best way ot achieve this.

Does anybody know of any existing HTML components, or even examples, that show how to present large number of events in a timeline?

And any recommendations/thoughts on a suitable backend for storing this? There is a fairly large number of events, and we'd be storing it going back (e.g. 6 months) - and we'd want the Web UI to be quite responsive panning back and forth, and looking up events.

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the backend I'd say go with Node.js and MongoDB, you're going to be doing a lot of IO to retrieve your data. For the front-end, you may want to take a look at google charts [annotated timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline) for displaying the data.